# How to calculate the leap year DAY?

Tags: c

So the user enters the year + it tells whether or not it is a leap year.. but now i need help getting the DAY of the week to pop up when it IS a leap year.

```
# include <math.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int yearEntered;

    printf("Enter a year: ");

    int read = scanf("%d", &yearEntered);

    if (read == 0 )
    {
        printf("Bad input: requires an integer");
    }
    else if (yearEntered%4==0 && yearEntered%100!=0 || yearEntered%400==0)
    {
        printf("%04d is a leap year and February 29th is on a \n",yearEntered, dayString);

    // Not so sure about this switch statement......
    switch (DayOfWeek)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            dayString("Sunday");
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            dayString("Monday");
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            dayString("Tuesday");
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            dayString("Wednesday");
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            dayString("Thursday");
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            dayString("Friday");
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            dayString("Saturday");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            dayString("");
        }

    }

    else if (yearEntered < 1752)
    {
        printf("%04d is not a 4 digit year after 1752.",yearEntered);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n",yearEntered);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the day of Feb 29th?

Comment: Are you sure your condition to detect leap years is good? A leap year is divisible by 4 or 100 but not 400.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Comment: @Eregrith: (4 && 100) || (400) is the same. Just repeating the checks

Comment: Also you have a switch in the middle of your else/if blocks. Work on this code more !

Comment: You don't declare `dayString`; you use it like a function; you pass it to `printf()` but don't print it; if it is a variable, you use it before you set its value.  There are things called arrays that can reduce the `switch` to nothing.

Comment: @noMAD ah yes I remembered badly

Comment: This code does not even compile. If you want some help try to have a [short self contained and compilable](http://sscce.org/) chunk

Comment: Thanks... some how it was easier than i thought.

Comment: fwiw ((0==year/400) || ((0!=year/100) && (0==year/4)). 1900 was not a leap year, 2100 was not either, but 2000 *was*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem were only about the day of week for Feb 29th, you'd just have to compute day of week for Feb 28th and increment it (modulo seven of course).

But I guess that your problem is to find day of week, no matter which particular day.

In that case, you may be interested in what Wikipedia has to say: [Determination of the day of the week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week).